# Single Sorted Linked List - Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error, infinite-loop, sortedlist

I'm working with a single linked list and I want to sort it from lower to higher values of integer. I though I had the idea but then the execution enters in a infinite loop and I can't see clearly why. This is the part of the code I worked with:

```
class Node {

    int data;
    Node* next;

public:

    Node() { };
    void SetData(int aData) { data = aData; };
    void SetNext(Node* aNext) { next = aNext; };
    int Data() { return data; };
    Node* Next() { return next; };
};

class List {

    Node *head;

public:

    List() { head = NULL; };
    void Print();
    void Append(int data);
    void Delete(int data);
};

void List::Append(int data) {

    // Create a new node
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->SetData(data);
    newNode->SetNext(NULL);

    // Create a temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    if ( tmp != NULL ) {
        // Nodes already present in the list
        // Parse to end of list anytime the next data has lower value
        while ( tmp->Next() != NULL && tmp->Next()->Data() <= newNode->Data() ) {
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        }

        // Point the lower value node to the new node
        tmp->SetNext(newNode);
        newNode->SetNext(tmp->Next());
    }
    else {
        // First node in the list
        head = newNode;
    }
}

void List::Print() {

    // Temp pointer
    Node *tmp = head;

    // No nodes
    if ( tmp == NULL ) {
        cout << "EMPTY" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // One node in the list
    if ( tmp->Next() == NULL ) {
        cout << tmp->Data();
        cout << " --> ";
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // Parse and print the list
        do {
            cout << tmp->Data();
            cout << " --> ";
            tmp = tmp->Next();
        }
        while ( tmp != NULL );

        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm confused if the list increases infinitely or the error comes from the Print function...
Sorry for the, perhaps, dummy errors.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have solved both the infinite loop issue as well as corrected the implementation. See my answer for a working example.

Comment: @oldrinb Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. This is what I tried to do with the list: A simulation for blocking probability in a telephone system.

http://d.pr/f/vkrf

Answer (score 0):

```
// Point the lower value node to the new node
tmp->SetNext(newNode);
newNode->SetNext(tmp->Next());
```

Since you overwrite `tmp->next` in the first call, your second call is actually pointing `newNode->next` towards `newNode` itself, creating a cycle. This causes your infinite loop when calling `Print` ;-)

The solution is to do something like as follows...

```
Node* _next = tmp->Next();
tmp->SetNext(newNode);
newNode->SetNext(_next);
```

That being said, your code is still broken. The problems is that you don't check whether you need to place *before* the head of the list; try doing something as follows..

```
if ( tmp ) {
    // Check whether to become new head
    if ( tmp->Data() > newNode->Data() ) {
      newNode->SetNext(tmp);
      head = newNode;
    }
    else {
      // Nodes already present in the list
      // Parse to end of list anytime the next data has lower value
      while ( tmp->Next() && tmp->Next()->Data() <= newNode->Data() ) {
          tmp = tmp->Next();
      }

      // Point the lower value node to the new node
      Node* _next = tmp->Next();
      tmp->SetNext(newNode);
      newNode->SetNext(_next);
  }
}
else {
    // First node in the list
    head = newNode;
}
```

---

Side note: you can use an initializer list to rewrite code like...

```
List() : head(NULL) { };
```

In addition, if `NULL` is equivalent to `0`, you can simplify conditions of the form `X == NULL` and `X != NULL` as merely `X` and `!X`, respectively.

---

See my [ideone paste](http://ideone.com/3qF6f) for the corrected version with an example.

```
int main() {
    List l;
    l.Append(15);
    l.Append(40);
    l.Append(7);
    l.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

... which produces

> 7 --> 15 --> 40 --> NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is these two lines:

```
tmp->SetNext(newNode);
newNode->SetNext(tmp->Next());
```

You should reverse them. Right now, you set tmp.next = newNode, and then newNode.next = tmp.next (= newNode), so newNode points to itself. Then traversing past newNode leads to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are failing to link two existing nodes properly.  Look at this fragment of your code:

```
tmp->SetNext(newNode);
newNode->SetNext(tmp->Next());
```

If for example you have this list:

head ->  5

and you want to insert a node with number 4 you will have:

head  ->  5  <-  tmp
newNode -> 4

With tmp->SetNext(newNode)

head (and tmp) ->  5 -> 4 <- newNode

With newNode->SetNext(tmp->Next());

head (and tmp) ->  5 -> 4 <- newNode

So any attempt to iterate through the list will result in and infinite loop:

5
4
4
4
4 ...... forever